Implication of 俺の独断以上にするのはまずい in this context
While reading a story, i met a vague part in a dialogue and not sure about its implication/ meaning. Hope some Japanese experts could give opinions to help me understand clearly what did this character mean/ implied here!
*full sentence: 「俺たちだけだったら言ってたけどさ。あの時は皇甫嵩や公孫賛との共同作戦だったし、さすがに俺の独断以上にするのはまずいだろ」>>My understanding but not sure: "....If you (the clan leader 桃香) do more than just my own arbitrarily decision, it would have been bad for you if they (皇甫嵩 and 公孫賛) found out" ?
*Story: Protagonist/一刀 is serving a clan leader 桃香 and her 2 other sisters 愛紗 +鈴々, to govern a region 平原 for the Imperial court. He just revealed a truth that he didn't want to tell with the clan leader and her sisters, that he knew about the true identities of the 3 leaders of the Yellow turban bandit - then spared their lives and let them escaped. Previously the protagonist together with these 3 sisters, had participated in a military campaign of the Imperial court, in order to defeat the Yellow turban bandit. They teamed up with a province governor/公孫賛 and an Imperial court general/皇甫嵩, and managed to defeat the Yellow turban army. The protagonist explained the reason- why he tried to hide this information, it's because he doesn't want them to get involved (i guess if the Imperial court found out, the clan leader + her other 2 sisters would be punished ?)
桃香「あの旅芸人の三人が……黄巾党の首領？」
そして俺は、改めて……黄巾党との決戦の日の事。張角たち三姉妹を見逃した件を話した。
証拠はないけど、俺はほぼ確信している。
愛紗「なるほど。そう言われると、確かに辻褄が合いますね」
桃香「……そっか。だから、平原が巻き込まれないように……わたしたちと一緒に来ないって言ってくれたんだ」
一刀「朱里の分析でも、何かの巡り合わせが悪くてああなっちゃったんだろうってさ。三人も、黄巾党みたいなのはこりごりって言ってたし」
内心、黄巾党の勢力が盛り返したらどうしようとはずっと思ってたんだけど……それがないって事は、彼女たちの気持ちは本物だったんだろう。
鈴々「あの三人、無事に逃げ切れたのかな？」
愛紗「黄巾絡みで何か動きがあれば、張遼や陳宮も教えてくれただろう。張角の正体は、結局あの角の化け物のままなのではないか？」
一刀「俺もそう思う。まあ、平和になったら平原に遊びに来るって言ってたし、詳しい話はその時に聞けばいいよ」
桃香たちにバレたって知られたら、張宝あたりにはすごく怒られそうな気がするけど…
桃香たちも罰するつもりはないだろうし、きっとそれをダシに色々と話が出来るはずだ。
桃香「そうだね……。でも、言ってくれたらわたしだっていくらでも協力したよ。ご主人様のほうが水くさいよ」
一刀「俺たちだけだったら言ってたけどさ。あの時は皇甫嵩や公孫賛との共同作戦だったし、さすがに俺の独断以上にするのはまずいだろ」
桃香「それはそうかもしれないけど…………」
鈴々「でもお姉ちゃんも嘘がヘタだから、きっとすぐバレちゃうのだ」
桃香「えーっ。鈴々ちゃん、ひどーい！」

The literal translation of 俺の独断以上にする is "to make it something beyond my own judgment". In this context, it effectively means to share the matter and solve it together with his close allies including 桃香.

俺たちだけだったら言ってたけどさ。
If it was just us, I would've told you.
あの時は皇甫嵩や公孫賛との共同作戦だったし
But it was a joint operation with 皇甫嵩 and 公孫賛, so...
俺の独断以上にするのはまずいだろ。
it was unwise to go beyond my own judgment, right?

This implies that sharing the information about 黄巾党 with his allies would have put them at a disadvantage in some way or another.

just to be clear, his "allies" here including just the 3 sisters , or everyone with both the 皇甫嵩 and 公孫賛 ? The writer didn't wrote specifically about this so i still confused. Also "to go beyond my own decision/judgement" mean "get more people involved in my decision of let the 3 leaders of Yellow turban bandit escape" ?

@MemoriesPlastic Just the characters in this particular scene. I think the protagonist is saying that, although it was fine for the three sisters to know about the 黄巾党 matter, if 皇甫嵩 and 公孫賛 had realized that the sisters knew about the matter, it would've been troublesome.
